# Compiling two files in CCTools Android (GCC Addon installed)

Tags: android, c, gcc, compilation

I have 3 files,

1) q5.c
2) q5.h
3) q5fun.c

The contents of each file is listed below,

q5.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "q5.h"
 int number;
 main() {
 number = 2;
 printf("%d\n",fun(5));
 printf("%d\n",number);
 }
```

q5.h

```
extern int number;
int fun(int);
```

q5fun.c

```
#include "q5.h"
int fun(int x) {
return x + number++;
}
```

On linux, code works fine. I am trying to make my platform mobile on a ground vehicle and I wanted to do such computations on my phone. 
I installed CCTools and the GCC add-on to it,

When I compile the main program "q5.c", the compiler throws up saying "undefined reference to 'fun'. What is the terminal command am I suppose to execute?
In unix platform I run "cc q5.c q5fun.c"
Under android platform, what am I suppose to run?

Comment: i have tried following terminal commands:
gcc q5.c q5fun.c -o myprogram  
It compiles successfully.
when I try executing the output, 
./myprogram

It states that "Permission Denied"

Comment: Okay seems I can compile and produce the output the way I want. Now the problem is that a.out file does not have execute permission. Any quick tips on how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Okay seems I can compile and produce the output the way I want. Now the problem is that a.out file does not have execute permission. Any quick tips on how to solve?

--

Execution from sdcard disabled by default for non-rooted devices. Copy your file to terminal home directory (it defined as /data/data/com.pdaxrom.cctools/root/cctools/home), change permission and run it:

```
cp myprogram ~/
chmod 755 ~/myprogram
~/myprogram
```

Also, you can use Makefile to compile two or more sources files.